# Multivalued PDE problem on Evans

Tags: partial-differential-equations, multivalued-functions

I'm reading Evans textbook, on chapter 8 there is a problem about multivalued PDE page 523 problem 8.7.14:

Show the variational inequality

$$\int_U Du\cdot D(w-u) \, dx\geq \int_U f(w-u) \, dx$$

For all $w\in H_0^1(U)$, $w\geq h$ a.e. in $U$. Can be rewritten as

$$-\Delta u+\beta (u-h)\ni f$$

For the multivalued function

\begin{equation}
\beta(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } x>0, \\
(-\infty,0], & \text{if } x=0, \\
\emptyset, & \text{if } x<0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Who can explain this formula for me? Or give some reference about this. Thank all of you!

Comment: This is super late, but I think this problem can be done by looking at the interpretation of the variational inequality which comes right after the proof of the inequality itself. At least I think so.